# Closure object becomes undefined in inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's been a while since I've toyed with my JS, so I might be missing something completely obvious. I have the following:

```
MyApp.IaeCheckboxCallback = function ($trigger) {
    var $checkbox = $trigger.find('input[type="checkbox"]');

    $checkbox.on('click', function () {
        doIAECallbackNT($trigger.attr('id'), $trigger.data('data-recordid'), $trigger.data('data-recordtype'),
        $trigger.data('data-valuejs'), $trigger.data('data-statuselement'), $trigger.data('data-callback'))
    });
};
```

Once inside $checkbox.on, $trigger becomes undefined. How do I prevent this?

**Adding more relevant code**

I'm tying into this other developer's JS that is in another script file.

```
function doIAECallbackNT
(
    iaeId,
    recordId,
    recordType,
    fieldName,
    value,
    statusElementId
)
{
    doIAECallbackNT(iaeId, recordId, recordType, fieldName, value, statusElementId, function(success) { });
}    

function doIAECallbackNT
(
    iaeId,
    recordId,
    recordType,
    fieldName,
    value,
    statusElementId,
    callback
)
{
    var req = newXMLHttpRequestNT ();
    var statusElement = document.getElementById(statusElementId);
    setStatusNT(statusElement, "Updating...");

    var msg = 
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
                "<soap:Body>" +
                    "<HandleRequest xmlns='https://somesite.com/WebService/'>" +
                        "<iaeId>" + iaeId + "</iaeId>" +
                        "<recordId>" + recordId + "</recordId>" +
                        "<recordType>" + recordType + "</recordType>" +
                        "<fieldName>" + fieldName + "</fieldName>" +
                        "<value>" + escape(value) + "</value>" +
                    "</HandleRequest>" +
                "</soap:Body>" +
            "</soap:Envelope>";

    //alert(msg);

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            var success = false;
            try { success = (req.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Success")[0].text.toLowerCase() == "true"); }
            catch (e) { success = false; }

            var msg2 = "";
            //var msg3 = "";
            try { msg2 = req.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Message")[0].text; }
            catch (e) { msg2 = req.responseText; }
            //msg3 = msg2;

            if (!success) {                
                //Error: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 2. 
                if ( msg2.indexOf("valid DateTime") != -1 )
                    msg2 = "Failed: You entered an invalid date. Please re-enter the date.";

                if (msg2.indexOf("StartDate_Must_Be_Before_EndDate") != -1)
                    msg2 = "Failed: The Start date must be prior to the End date. Try changing the start date first.";

                //alert(msg2);
                AddFailedNote(msg2);

                if (statusElement.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a') 
                    msg2 = "<span class='error bold'>" + msg2 + "</span>";
            }
            else if (statusElement.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a') {
                AddSuccessNote(msg2);
                msg2 = "<span class='success bold'>" + msg2 + "</span>";
            }

            setStatusNT(statusElement, msg2);
            if (callback != null) { callback(success); }
        }
    };
    req.open("POST", "../Services/IAEService.asmx", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", msg.length.toString());
    req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "https://www.somesite.com/WebService/HandleRequest");
    req.send(msg);
}
```

and here's the ugly .NET rendering of a checkbox:

```
<span class="IaeCheckboxCallback" title="Ent?" data-recordid="11012" data-recordtype="Person" data-fieldname="HasEnterprise" data-statuselement="MainContent_MainContent_hrmol3_sp_ctl00" data-callback="function() { }" data-valuejs="MainContent_MainContent_hrmol3_dp_ctl00_0.checked" style="font-size:1em;"><input id="MainContent_MainContent_hrmol3_dp_ctl00_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$hrmol3$dp$0$tc_HasEnterprise$ctl00" /></span>
```

The other person's code fails at: f (statusElement.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a')

All the parameters that I've passed in show as undefined in the browser developer tool.

Comment: Is `$trigger` `DOM` element ? Tried calling `$trigger` as parameter of `jQuery.fn.init()` `var $checkbox = $($trigger).find('input[type="checkbox"]');` ?

Comment: It shouldn't be undefined... What's the error do you receive?

Comment: It looks like it should be e.g `$trigger.data('recordid')` not `$trigger.data('data-recordid')`. So are you sure this is `$trigger` which is undefined, not the datas you are trying to target?

Comment: Karl - Inside the doIAECallbackNT function, I get "Unable to get property 'tagName' of undefined or null reference" when it's trying to use the statuselement parameter. Using a debugger, it seems that all the parameters passed in are null.

Comment: A. Wolff - Yes, you are right. I updated that, but the doIAECallbackNT function still reports the parameters as being undefined.

Comment: You have to provide all relevant code in question itself and with a minimalistic code to replicate issue. Here, you are just letting us guessing what could be wrong, and there is many possibilities...

Comment: @getoutofmylaboratory Is `$trigger` DOM element  http://jsfiddle.net/gomaqw8u/ ?

Comment: @guest271314 Are you OP? If ya, i don't see how your jsFiddle is supposed to help, you haven't define any data attribute

Comment: @A.Wolff No. Not OP. Only attempting to reduce possibilties of `undefined` being returned as error. If `$trigger` is DOM element , will not reach `.data("data-*")`

Comment: @guest271314 Ya it won't, but is it OP's issue??? EDIT: ok i see, this was regarding your former comment: `$($trigger)`  I see what you mean now ;)

Comment: I've added some more relevant code to my post.

Comment: It is not `$trigger` that is undefined - otherwise, you would have seen the error much earlier - when parameters for `doIAECallbackNT` are prepared. Your answer is the first comment by @A.Wolff - remove `data-` from all `.data` calls. Btw, are you trying to overload `doIAECallbackNT` function? This will not work in javascript.

Comment: Igor - I have already removed the data- bits from the code. The doIAECallbackNT function has been like that years before I ever looked at it. But yes, it does look like the original developer is trying to overload it. I also tried hardcoding the values into my function and they still show as undefined. So perhaps it's the attempt at overloading that other function that is the problem?

Comment: *sigh* Not only was I using 'data-' inside the `data()` function...I wasn't passing the correct number of parameters to the doIAECallbackNT function. I was off by one. It's now passing it the correct data :/

Comment: The second definition of `doIAECallbackNT` completely hides the first. You can remove or comment out the first definition. If even `doIAECallbackNT` call with  hardcoded parameters makes them undefined inside `doIAECallbackNT`, then you need to post that code - it at least rules out the possibility of wrong `$trigger` variable.